# Why is my variable returning undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I am new to javascript. I am making a flashcard program. For some reason, despite defining the variable lastPress as global, lastPress seems to return undefined. However, it is not resulting in an error in JSHint. Here's my code:

```js
var i = 0;
var questions = ["1: Was the human migration caused by an ice age?", "True"];
var answer = [true, true];
var lastPress;
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[i];
function itsTrue() {
    lastPress = true;
}
function itsFalse() {
    lastPress = false;
}
function getAns() {
    if (answer[i] == lastPress) {
        document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "You're correct! The answer was " + lastPress;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "We're sorry, but that is not correct. You said " + lastPress + ". The answer was " + answer[i];
    }
    i++;
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[i];
}
document.getElementById("true").onclick = function(){itsTrue()};
document.getElementById("true").onclick = function(){getAns()};
document.getElementById("false").onclick = function(){itsFalse()};
document.getElementById("false").onclick = function(){getAns()};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flash cards</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="question">This is where the question shows up</p>
        <p id="ans">This is where the result will show up</p>
        <button type="button" id="true">True</button>
        <button type="button" id="false">False</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to define multiple functions to the same click event:  also, after the second press on your true false buttons i is incremented to 2 thus questions[2] is undefined

```js
var i = 0;
            var questions = ["1: Was the human migration caused by an ice age?", "True"];
            var answer = [true, true];
            var lastPress;
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[i];
            function itsTrue() {
                console.log('true')
                lastPress = true;                
            }
            function itsFalse() {
                console.log('false');
                lastPress = false;                
            }
            function getAns() {
                if (answer[i] == lastPress) {
                    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "You're correct! The answer was " + lastPress;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "We're sorry, but that is not correct. You said " + lastPress + ". The answer was " + answer[i];
                }
                i++;
                console.log(i);
                document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[i];
            }
            document.getElementById("true").onclick = function(){itsTrue();getAns();};
            //document.getElementById("true").onclick = function(){getAns()};
            document.getElementById("false").onclick = function(){itsFalse(),getAns();};
           //  document.getElementById("false").onclick = function(){getAns()};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flash cards</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="question">This is where the question shows up</p>
        <p id="ans">This is where the result will show up</p>
        <button type="button" id="true">True</button>
        <button type="button" id="false">False</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear, in your question, what returned undefined so i assumed it was what was updated in your HTML.

Your code returns undefined because you are incrementing `i` at each click. But your array is only, two element long. You need to handle the fact that all your question has been shown. Here i've simply reset the variable `i` to 0, but i'm not sure if that applies in your case.

```js
var i = 0;
            var questions = ["1: Was the human migration caused by an ice age?", "2. this is a second question, true or false ? ", "3. did i got you with my last tricky question?"];
            var answer = [true, true, false];
            var lastPress;
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[i];
            function itsTrue() {
                lastPress = true;
            }
            function itsFalse() {
                lastPress = false;
            }
            function getAns() {
                if (answer[i] == lastPress) {
                    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "You're correct! The answer was " + lastPress;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "We're sorry, but that is not correct. You said " + lastPress + ". The answer was " + answer[i];
                }
                i++;
                if(i >= questions.length) {
                  i = 0;
                }
                document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[i];
            }
            document.getElementById("true").onclick = function(){itsTrue(); getAns() };
            document.getElementById("false").onclick = function(){itsFalse(); getAns()};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flash cards</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="question">This is where the question shows up</p>
        <p id="ans">This is where the result will show up</p>
        <button type="button" id="true">True</button>
        <button type="button" id="false">False</button>
    </body>
</html>
```